# Georeferencing scanned map using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, georeferencing

Using ArcMap 9.3, I want to georeference a scanned map of Sudan (Africa) as .jpg file format,coordinate points are marked on scanned map in 4 degree intervals. I am not familiar to georeferencing in ArcMap.

So looking for a detail guide line for georeferencing in ArcMap (using 4 control points) and also looking for a guide line to edit the spatial reference in base map with the suitable PCS information for the AOI.

Comment: Googling "georeference a scanned map ArcGIS 10" produces loads of good answers.

Comment: if the coordinates and pixel size of the image are known a jpw or jpgw text file can be created without manually georeferencing image in ArcMap. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t00000028000000.htm

Comment: Doing this programmatically would be difficult - Esri doesn't expose the arcobjects for ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoReferenceUI.

Comment: but you can do it outside the 'esri gis' loop with excel and simple dos .bat files - found it much more efficient for tens of thousands of .pngs for a web/desktop app.

Answer (score 4):

Read this PDF. All the steps are clearly illustrated - Georeferencing of Scanned Maps & Spatial Adjustment of Vector Data - http://www.library.yale.edu/MapColl/files/docs/Georeferencing%20of%20Scanned%20Maps.pdf

Answer (score 1):

See the [ESRI link](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Georeferencing_a_raster_dataset) for the same...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Esri video: [Georeferencing Rasters in ArcGIS](http://video.arcgis.com/watch/376/georeferencing-rasters-in-arcgis).

Here also short guide (2 pages): [Georeferencing Images in ArcMap](http://www.gistrainingsource.com/Resources/Georeferencing.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following the instructions at [Fundamentals of georeferencing a raster dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/fundamentals-for-georeferencing-a-raster-dataset.htm):

> Raster data is commonly obtained by scanning maps or collecting aerial
>   photographs and satellite images. Scanned map datasets don't normally
>   contain spatial reference information (either embedded in the file or
>   as a separate file). With aerial photography and satellite imagery,
>   sometimes the location information delivered with them is inadequate,
>   and the data does not align properly with other data you have. Thus,
>   to use some raster datasets in conjunction with your other spatial
>   data, you may need to align or georeference them to a map coordinate
>   system.